# How to access strict/explicit href value with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Given the following anchor:

`<a class="example" href="record1234">link</a>`

How can the actual value of `href` be retrieved with vanilla Javascript?

```
const link = document.querySelector('.example');

console.log(link.href);
// https://exampledomain.com/current/document/path/record1234

console.log(link.pathname)
// /current/document/path/record1234

// with jQuery
$('.example').attr('href');

// what I want to do:
console.log(link.href.string); // record1234
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) on the element.

```js
const link = document.querySelector('.example');
console.log(link.getAttribute('href'));
```

```html
<a class="example" href="record1234">link</a>
```